# Print a java object as JSON string after sorting its keys and values

Tags: java, json, string, sorting

I have a java object with multiple keys and the values can be arrays list. I want to print the object as a JSON string but the output should have the keys and values sorted. In the case of values, sorting should be in the array itself (if any)

For example, I have the POJO for this JSON representation

```
{
"d": ["d","a", "r"],
"c": "arr",
"a": "2020-10-01:00:00"
}
```

The expected output should be like:

```
{"a": "2020-10-01:00:00", "c": "arr", "d": ["d","a", "r"]}
```

In the output, the keys are sorted relative to each other but the value array is sorted within itself.

Comment: Can you share the POJO which is representing this JSON ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort based on the key only use below code and JSON Dependency (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20140107)-

```
String[] arr = { "d", "a", "r" };

Map<String, Object> data = new TreeMap<>();
data.put("d", arr);
data.put("c", "arr");
data.put("a", "2020-10-01:00:00");

JSONObject sortedDate = new JSONObject(data);
System.out.println(sortedDate);
```